# What is "The Evil Organization"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, neologisms

Recently I clicked on a "hot" topic from Information Security.SE titled...

[***Buying a “Used” Router***](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/203859/buying-a-used-router)

A number of times the term "***Evil Organization***" came up in the comments. As in...

> ***The Evil Organization*** would have to predict when I am going to buy a router, predict which make/model I will buy, where I will buy, go there before, buy all the routers on the place, put a backdoor on each one, return every one, and wait for me to buy the compromised router. I don't think is plausible..

Is this a reference to the *[TV trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NebulousEvilOrganisation)* such as in [the series Mr. Robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Robot), or is it some kind of sardonic reference to a conspiracy-theory driven paranoia? Or maybe they are serious?

Comment: It refers back to "intelligence agencies" (with malicious intent) in the preceding sentence.

Comment: It's just giving a name to a concept so that there is a way to refer to it throughout. Functionally, it's no different than "***an*** evil organization" ...

Comment: Hi @TRomano ..that was a very astute observation. I had to go back and look. [extremely interested]. I would like to find out if there is a recognized concept, as in perhaps, tech world, or like in programmer-speak. Perhaps I am unclear.

Comment: It is intended to be a generic label for "bad (institutional) actor" and the uppercase letters add a little ominous organ music appropriate for "cloak and dagger" operations.

Comment: Erm...lemme think about that @TRomano. That was my first take, but...just as most of the net is on the dark side, maybe there is term that describes this with the tekkie guys...?? Perhaps it has an idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 2):

In my reading, they are not talking about any specific organization, but are referring to the idea mentioned in the answer and the previous comment that an evil actor might have tampered with the router.

I read it like this: *"The Evil Organization implied by your question would have to..."*

Comment: Exactly.  The reader is allowed to substitute whatever organization s/he thinks is Evil - the NSA, the KGB, the National Enquirer...